# Running Parse Server over Intranet

Tags: parse-server, intranet, wifi

Can I use Parse Server to provision service to my app that runs over intranet (a local server and multiple clients) using WLAN? If yes, how can this be achieved? if no why can't it.

No internet connection is supported yet for the app. It is designed to be used in-house only intranet via WLAN or LAN.

So far all I've seen are ways to host parse-server to one cloud infrastructure or the other.

Comment: Are you just wanting to setup port forwarding from WLAN to LAN?

Comment: yes. Also how can i make my devices access the server over intranet as i'm a newbie to this

Comment: Depends on your router, but I bet you can lookup how to access its admin interface, get your public IP address, then setup port forwarding, and that should get you most of the way there

Comment: why would you need public IP serving if the devices are run over intranet. I would guess that the devices are also running on the local lan hence access to the intranet

Answer (score 0):

You can easily host a parse server on your intranet.

Follow the guide and clone the parse server [example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example)

Follow the guide below (taken from the github example) for local development to get aquianted with how you set it up

- Make sure you have at least Node 4.3. node --version
- Clone this repo and change directory to it.
- npm install
- Install mongo locally using http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/
- Run mongo to connect to your database, just to make sure it's working. Once you see a mongo prompt, exit with Control-D
- Run the server with: npm start
- By default it will use a path of /parse for the API routes. To change this, or use older client SDKs, run export PARSE_MOUNT=/1
  before launching the server.
- You now have a database named "dev" that contains your Parse data

Comment: how can i connect my devices to the local server as i'm a newbie to this

Comment: You need to point the client library to the local server. E.g. running parse server on ip 192.168.1.100 then setup (for javascript) would be Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID"); Parse.serverURL = 'http://192.168.1.100:1337/parse'